# Tartuffe de Molière : "Raijon" et "fiche"

Tags: oral

En lisant le Tartuffe de Molière [le livre est dans Hachette : Collection Lecture Facile FLE (français langue étrangère) raconté par Vincent Leroger mais on peut l'emprunter ici https://archive.org/details/collectionlectur00moli/page/n3]
on voit (p. 27) :

> Tu as raijon, mon fiche...

(C'est la mère d'Orgon s'adressant à lui.)

Ces deux mots, *raijon* et *fiche*, sont-ils des variantes archaïques de *raison* et *fils*, respectivement ? Sont-ils des maniérismes ?

Voici l'extrait :

[image]

Comment: Une présentation du texte (et donc du contexte) qui eût été plus heureuse si elle eût été faite de prime abord, et non des mois après la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/30858/13100) de Circeus, qui semble désormais être tombée entre deux chaises...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non, c'est un défaut d'élocution (sigmatisme dorsal pour être exact, je crois). C'est aussi le genre de déformation qui est fréquemment employée pour indiquer que quelqu'un est fin saoul.

(Avec l'ajout du passage depuis que j'ai répondu, c'est la réponse de jiliagre qui est la meilleure!)

Answer (score 10):

L'explication est clairement indiquée après le texte en question :

> qui avait un énorme morceau de patisserie dans la bouche.

Mme Pernelle, dans cette très libre interprétation de l’œuvre originale de Molière (d'où cette scène est absente), prononce difficilement les mots en italique non pas à cause d'un défaut d'élocution mais simplement parce qu'elle a de la nourriture dans la bouche...

Comment: Ha oui! +1! Avec le texte, tout s'explique désormais. Je me demandais aussi ce qui avait bien pu pousser une maison d'édition sérieuse à balancer de la retranscription d'accent régional à des apprenants de FLE.